# Connecting to Nagios Api via Website

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, api, nagios

I am trying to connect to my Nagios server through a website to display to state of the hosts on the Nagios server.

I have run the curl command and I get a json response back and it works. But now when I try to connect for the web app it jQuery gives me a GET 401 unauthorized error.

```
jquery-3.1.0.js:9392 GET http://41.87.218.55/nagios/cgi-bin/objectjson.cgi?query=hostlist&parenthost=none&childhost=none 401 (Unauthorized)
send  @ jquery-3.1.0.js:9392
ajax @ jquery-3.1.0.js:8999
getData @ myJavaAng.js:187
(anonymous function) @ myJavaAng.js:203
```

My code:

```
function getData() {
  var name, code;
  var serviceURL = "http://test:welcome@41.87.218.55/nagios/cgi-bin/objectjson.cgi?query=hostlist&parenthost=none&childhost=none";
  $.support.cors = true;
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "json",
    crossDomain: true,
    url: serviceURL,
    success: function(data) {
      alert(data);
    },
    error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
      console.log(errorThrown);
    }
  });
}
```

Please let me know what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is for anyone who has the same problem I did.

The nagios server was not accepting the Javascript or jQuery that I was using to connect to the API. This is because of a Same-origin Policy.

Here is a simple PHP script that does the samething.

```
<?php
$url = 'http://test:welcome@41.87.218.55/nagios/cgi-bin/objectjson.cgi?query=hostlist&parenthost=none&childhost=none';
$obj = json_decode(file_get_contents($url), true);

print_r($obj);
?>
```

Hope this helps anyone who has the same problem.